# How can i convert a CodeVariableDeclarationStatement to CodeAssignmentStatement.?

Tags: c#

```
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement hashTableParam = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement();
hashTableParam.Name = "hastable";
hashTableParam.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.Collections.Hashtable));
CodeMethodInvokeExpression invokeExp2 =
    new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(hashTableParam.Name), "add");
invokeExp2.Parameters.Add(new CodeArgumentReferenceExpression("key"));
invokeExp2.Parameters.Add(new CodeArgumentReferenceExpression("value"));
return hashTableParam;
```

I need to use the above code in a method that returns, CodeAssignStatement.? how can i do so.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only sensible `CodeAssignStatement` in the above would be something like (untested):

```
       CodeAssignStatement assign = new CodeAssignStatement(
            new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(hashTableParam.Name),
            new CodeObjectCreateExpression(hashTableParam.Type));
```

However, this assignment (returned at this point) won't include the key/value addition. What exactly is it you are trying to do?